# Before closing window Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Is there a way in Sublime Text to detect before window is closing to add a custom command?

I run a custom command with this shortcuts:

```
[
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+w"], "command": "custom_command"},
{ "keys": ["alt+f4"], "command": "custom_command"}
]
```

But there are other ways to close Sublime Text and makes sense that a before closing window event should cover all.

Answer (score 1):

There is an event handler function that gets called before a view is closed. I think the name of the function you need is

```
on_pre_close(view)
```

All event handler functions are listed within the Sublime Text 3 API. I didn't find one for when the window is closed but I think when the window is going to close, it should close each view first, so using the above function should solve your problem. Here is the link to the Event Listeners section of the API. It should help you.

https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.EventListener

Incase you are new to building plugins, 
Note that to use Event Listener functions you will need to have a plugin in which you have a class like this

```
class your_class_name(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_pre_close(self,view):
        #Your code here
```

Comment: Actually I am trying to update this plugin: https://github.com/tuvistavie/SublimeHotProjectExit/blob/master/hot_project_exit.py I'm indeed new to this. So now I have to replace #Your code here with running the command hot_project_exit. How I do that?. I suspect that it doesn't matter anyway because in the plugin it looks like the word view is used. So when on_pre_close(view) will run the command will be to late. I may be completely of because I don't actually know anything about building a Sublime Text plugin.

Comment: From what I can see, that plugin basically checks if there are any unsaved changes made to the buffer and then saves those changes and closes.
The slight problem that you might have here is that the plugin is implementing a Window Command ; not sure if it will be a problem or not. The first thing you can try is pasting the code from the run function and replacing #YourCodeHere with that code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe python's `atexit` https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html would work.
(I have not tried it - it is possible that python plugin API will not be fully working at the time `atexit` functions are called)

Comment: Unfortunately the `atexit` module doesn't help - it can not be used to run code when a Sublime Text window is closed nor even when the Sublime Text application is closed.